# List of String to Map Java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I have a list of String in my application. Every String is actually an output of 2 different strings concatenated by ".".
e.g. Stack.Overflow

Now, I am trying to convert this list to a Map with key being the first part of the string and value being the second part. e.g key=Stack and value=Overflow

I am doing something like this:

```
List<String> sampleList = someList here;

Map<String, String> outputMap= sampleList .stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(s->s.toString().split("\\.")[0],
s->s.toString().split("\\.")[1]));
```

How can it be achieved? Thanks

It doesn't seem to be working for me. See below:

```
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
    sample.add("12345.22-JUN-18");
    sample.add("12345.22-JUN-18");
    sample.add("45678.25-JUN-18");

    sample.add("23456.25-JUN-18");
    sample.add("34567.25-JUN-18");
    sample.add("67890.25-JUN-18");
    sample.add("45678.25-JUN-18");
    sample.add("23456.26-JUN-18");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.]");

    Map<String,String> output = sample.stream()
      .map(pattern::split)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));

It gives me java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 22-JUN-18.
```

Why is it taking the date as the key? It should have the date as the value not as a key.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? It seems to work on my machine

Comment: Your code is fine but you could just remove that unsatisfying need to call split twice, by doing it earlier in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have there is fine, assuming `\\.` matches the single character `.`.

However, you can clean it up a bit by compiling the regex into a `Pattern` and using `Stream#map`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.]");

Arrays.asList("Stack.Overflow")
      .stream()
      .map(pattern::split)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Output:

```
{Stack=Overflow}
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Please see my edit in the question above.

Comment: @user3262365 You have keys that map to multiple values (`23456` maps to `25-JUN-18` and `26-JUN-18`).  Would you like to collect it to a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead?

Comment: I should have instead got the duplicated issue with the numbers not the date. The exception I am getting is Duplicate key 22-JUN-18. It means it is trying to take the date as the key. Isn't it?

Comment: @user3262365 No, you're just using the same key twice (`12345`).  The solution is to either call `Stream#distinct` before the collecting occurs, or collect it to a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead.

Comment: Seems like the exception is misleading. It is showing the value as the key in the exception.

Comment: How can I collect it to  Map<String, List<String>> as you mentioned?

Comment: @user3262365 You can use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0]));`

Comment: It actually returns a Map<Object, Collection<String[]>>. I am expecting a Map with value as List<String> not List<String[]>. And the List should have the dates as the values.

Comment: @user3262365 My bad, it should have been `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0], Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], Collectors.toList())))`

Comment: Awesome!!! It did the trick. Thanks a lot Jacob G, you saved my day. :)

Comment: @user3262365 Happy to help!

Comment: when the pattern is a single dot, `String.split` is more efficient.